# How can I set Brewmaster's Pandarens to permanent control groups?

Tags: dota-2

How can I set Brewmaster's Pandarens to the same control groups permanently, so that I don't need to manually set them (i.e. ctrl+1, ctrl+2 etc) each time I use his ult?

Ideally I'd like Earth set to 1, Storm set to 2, and Fire set to 3 permanently, so I can micro immediately after the split.

Thanks!

Comment: I actually thought it already did this, after you've set them up...

Comment: I thought the same. Have you tried in game using Brew's ulti and using ctrl + 1/2/3 to set the brewling as you wish then restart a game and see if it kept what you selected before ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The other answers are correct.  If you assign control groups to each panda during his ult, those groups will persist into the next game, including between levelups and client resets.